# Why is Cindy Lou on the top of the sleigh?

Tags: character-motivation, dr-seuss, how-the-grinch-stole-christmas-2000

In the Jim Carrey version of *How the Grinch Stole Christmas*, the Grinch has a change of heart, his heart grows, and now he doesn't want to destroy Christmas. The sleigh of stolen presents starts sliding off the cliff and he tries to save them, but after some struggle, starts to consider abandoning hope, saying "well, they're  just presents, right?".

Then Cindy Lou is revealed to be on the very top of the bag of presents on the sleigh, meaning she is in danger should everything fall of the edge. The Grinch shouts, "Cindy Lou?!? What are you doing up there?" to which she responds "I came to see you. Nobody should be alone on Christmas". Coming to see him on the top of Mount Crumpit makes sense since he lives there. Climbing onto the very top of the sleigh, however, does not. Did she think the Grinch was hiding *inside* the bag or something? Why in the world was she *on top* of the bag on the sleigh (as opposed to simply knocking on his front door)? Is there any in-universe explanation?

Comment: She was no more than two. Two-year-olds do crazy things.

Comment: There's nothing in the film's novelisation that explains it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might ask "What was she doing there?"
She had looked for the Grinch everywhere.

She had looked high, she had looked low, her resolve started to fray.
"Wait a minute..." she wondered, "perhaps he is on top of the sleigh!"

So she climbed and she clambered, to the top of the sack,
"He must be there!" she thought, "There's no turning back!"

But the sleigh slipped and slid and seemed ready to fall.
She looked back down, there was the Grinch after all!

Comment: Is this fan-fic?

Comment: This might be the first answer on the site written in poetry.

Comment: I was responding in a vernacular that seemed appropriate to the question; if that fits your definition of *fan-fic* then I guess it is (but was never indeed to be).

Comment: While I applaud the effort, some might confuse an answer written in the form of a 'Seussian' poem for an answer that's quoting Seuss.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a directing decision and is meant to convey a sense of personal commitment on the part of Cindy Lou.  It is a completely over exaggerated dramatized scene which displays their overwhelming commitment to the task at hand and the right thing despite the personal risk.  Many directors and indie film directors do this and although it is a different company Disney is famous for these types of scenes.  One example that comes to mind is the scene in Oliver and Company where Dodger is singing Street Sidewalk Fare.  The whole scene is over exaggerated and is meant to display Dodgers free spirit and Oliver's commitment to persist after what he wants.

Comment: @RogueJedi No, but the fact that it's formulaic for children-targeted movies is relevant.

Comment: I know, I worded that poorly.  Please see my edit.